# Comparing struct values against variable

Tags: c, struct

I'm struggling to compare the contents of a struct to a variable. There are 10 structs in array1 with the variables value and count. I need to go through every value variable until I find the one matching tempVal and then increment the corresponding count, then the search can end. If it's not found the function will return -1.

I have the following code that runs fine but doesn't work, I have a feeling it may be something wrong with the strcmp line but I'm not sure. Cheers for any input.

```
int valCheck(char *tempVal){

    int j;
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        if(strcmp(array1[j].value, tempVal) == 0){ 
            array1[j].count++; //increment its count
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Edited full:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct values
{
    char value[64];
    int count;
};

struct values array1[100];

//check if value exists in array
int valCheck(char *tempVal)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(array1[j].value, tempVal) == 0)
        {
            array1[j].count++; //increment its count
            //return j; // <== return index of found element
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    FILE * input;
    int i;
    char tempVal[] ="hello";
    input = fopen("random.txt","r");

    for (i=0;i<=10;i++) //go through the 10 elements in text file
    {
        //scan each word into a temporary variable
        // **** NOT COMPLETE, JUST USING TEMPWORD ASSIGNED FOR NOW

        int checkedVal = valCheck(&tempVal);

        //if wordCheck returns -1 add the word to the array
        //otherwise do nothing as a duplicate has appeared
        if(checkedVal == -1){
            fscanf(input, "%s",array1[i].value);
        }

        printf("WORD %i: %s ",i,array1[i].value);
        printf(" COUNT IS: %i", array1[i].count);
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A **return value** is probably warranted, don't you agree? If this is supposed to indicate to the caller that `valCheck()` found the value and modified its count, and more importantly if that is what you're using for your basis of "this doesn't work" claim, you *might* want to actually communicate that fact via a `return` statement rather than some random value in the EAX register.

Comment: please define *doesn't work*. Also add the definition of your `array1[]` structure to the question.

Comment: From your code, no one can tell whats wrong. What is array1 ? What is tempVal

Comment: sorry array1 is just a array of structs "struct values array1[100];" using the struct "values" which contains value and count. tempVal is a char. It's mainly the comparison I'm struggling to get working.

Comment: Adding a `fprintf(stderr, "%d {%s,%s}\n", j, array1[j].value, tempVal);` inside the loop will probably enlighten you.

Comment: Function `strcmp` works for C strings, not for `struct`s. It stops when it finds the "null terminator", which could be an arbitrary zero embedded in your `struct`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm going to assume it would not *compile* if passed a structure pointer as either parameter to `strcmp()` I see no casts, and I do see a structure member denote (the `value` in `array1[j].value`). Knowing whether this *compiles* vs. fails-at-runtime would probably narrow quite a bit down.

Comment: `break` -> return j, for(...){...} return -1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- Your array is properly allocated (either on the stack or dynamically) to be at-least-10-elements wide.
- Your structure member `value` is a valid `char *` or fixed-length `char[n]` buffer.
- The string data references by the `value` member of your structure is properly null-terminated.
- The string data referenced by `tempVal` is valid and properly null-terminated.
- You're aware that `strcmp()` compares case-sensitively
- You're comment about 100 elements in the array and this code only checking the first **ten** (10) elements is intentional

My crystal ball tells me that ultimately you need to have your function actually **return** something.

```
int valCheck(char *tempVal)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(array1[j].value, tempVal) == 0)
        { 
            array1[j].count++; //increment its count
            return j; // <== return index of found element
        }
    }
    return -1;  // <== return -1 per your description of failure.
}
```

Note: Your compiler, equipped with decent warning-checks, would easily spot this lack-of-return code. Heed those warnings. Likewise, double-check everything in the bullet list at the top of this answer to make *sure* what you're going into this with is proper.

---

**EDIT** Updated to reflect sample dictionary build for OP.

The following is how I think this is likely to be called. Hope it helps you. I changed a few things:

- Made the dictionary a little bigger (256)
- Processes the command line to get the filename. Makes it easier for me to test.
- Only reports a summary at the end rather than per-word while processing.

I hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct values
{
    char value[64];
    int count;
};

// global array.
struct values array1[256];
int n_words = 0;

//check if value exists in array
int valCheck(const char *tempVal)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(array1[j].value, tempVal) == 0)
        {
            array1[j].count++; //increment its count
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * input = NULL;
    char tempVal[64];
    int i=0;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Must specify a filename.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // open file
    input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (!input)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // read all strings from the file one at a time.
    while (fscanf(input, "%64s", tempVal) == 1)
    {
        int i = valCheck(tempVal);
        if (i == -1)
        {
            if (n_words < sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]))
            {
                strcpy(array1[n_words].value, tempVal);
                array1[n_words].count = 1;
                i = n_words++;
            }
            else
            {   // error. no more space in dictionary
                printf("No more space to add word: %s\n", tempVal);
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(input);

    // summary report
    for (i=0;i<n_words;++i)
        printf("WORD %i: %s, COUNT IS: %i\n", i, array1[i].value, array1[i].count);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Input**

```
hello my name is dave hello I am dave hi
```

**Output**

```
WORD 0: hello, COUNT IS: 2
WORD 1: my, COUNT IS: 1
WORD 2: name, COUNT IS: 1
WORD 3: is, COUNT IS: 1
WORD 4: dave, COUNT IS: 2
WORD 5: I, COUNT IS: 1
WORD 6: am, COUNT IS: 1
WORD 7: hi, COUNT IS: 1
```

---

**Homework**

After all of that, I leave you to determine why the following code also works, but uses no temporary buffer to do so (sort of, anyway).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct values
{
    char value[64];
    int count;
};

// global array.
#define MAX_WORDS   256
struct values array1[MAX_WORDS] = {{{0},0}};
int n_words = 0;

//check if value exists in array
int valCheck(const char *tempVal)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j< n_words; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(array1[j].value, tempVal) == 0)
        {
            array1[j].count++; //increment its count
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * input = NULL;
    int i=0;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Must specify a filename.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // open file
    input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (!input)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // read all strings from the file one at a time.
    while (n_words < MAX_WORDS &&
           fscanf(input, "%64s", array1[n_words].value) == 1)
    {
        if (valCheck(array1[n_words].value) == -1)
        {
            array1[n_words].count = 1;
            ++n_words;
        }
    }
    fclose(input);

    // summary report
    for (i=0;i<n_words;++i)
        printf("WORD %i: %s, COUNT IS: %i\n", i, array1[i].value, array1[i].count);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same as before.

Comment: hmm it doesn't appear that my comparison code was too wrong then, so I must be making a problem elsewhere. I'm pretty sure all those assumptions are met apart from: 

-The string data references by the value member of your structure is properly null-terminated.
-The string data referenced by tempVal is valid and properly null-terminated. I've edited the OP if that helps

Comment: @user2209254 Your updated post will *always* return -1. That `return j` is there for a reason: to denote *success* (i.e. a non-(-1) return value. You could just as easily return 0. Anything will do, so long as it is NOT (-1) if you found a match.

Comment: ah sorry forgot about that! I did try returning 0 but then it only does the loop once and stops. the file just contains random words delimited by spaces. "hello my name is dave hello I am dave hi" - pretty random !

Comment: @user2209254 ok. So the premise is you're reading these strings in, looking them up in you up-to-one-hundred-word dictionary,and if they're already there, bump a reference count, otherwise add it. If that sounds correct you're closer than you may think. Scan the next word into a local var, then use valCheck() to determine if it is present. If it isn't (-1 returned), then add it. you need to keep track of how many words are in your dictionary to use as the top-end of how many comparisons to do, and increment that as you add words.  But the only bug in your checker, no ret-val, is fixed.

Comment: I did try assigning tempVal the next word in file rather than having a static value using "fscanf(input, "%s",tempVal);" and then in the "if(checkedVal == -1){" block assigning the word using "array1[i].value = tempVal;" but got no success either

Comment: @user2209254 If I have time I'll try and throw together something. Work is kind of pressing at the moment.

Comment: no worries! Cheers for the above paragraph that's most of what I needed to know, should be able to do the keeping track part, I'll keep browsing trying to get that line to work then might be done! The code will eventually have to be more dynamic in the way the array fits the data so no memory is wasted depending on the different files inputted. Which I have a feeling will require memory allocation which I know little about. But need it to work to begin with!

Comment: @user2209254 Ok. I hope that helps. Late for a meeting. Take care.

Comment: I need to allow the array to be created dynamically due to not knowing how many words could be in the text file each time it's ran. I did consider first searching the file, counting words and setting the array to that length before the processing occurs, but that will waste too much memory as duplicates will not be accounted for so the array will be much longer than necessary. Is it possible to increase the array length each time a word is added? Or is that a bad move in regards to processing power?